# DIfferent div tags using same CSS - how do I change that?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm having problems stylizing my footer. The footer is separated into 4 columns with HTML and all the columns are using same CSS styling

All I'm trying to do is align the right column text to the right, and center the middle column text.

In inspector when I try changing text-align, it's being applied to all columns. Is there a way I can change this within additional CSS section in WordPress or will I have to edit the code of this website theme?

[image]

Comment: If you'd like to apply different classes to different divs, you need to specify those classes in HTML structure. If all the divs have the same classes, they will be formatted in the same way.

Comment: You can play with **.mkdf-column-content:nth-child()** in CSS to address a particular column and keep the HTML as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ID as the selector to target just the one column, like so:

```
#text-5 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: As a beginner, to me this was the best answer because it was easiest to implement! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add specific classes for each column that you want to customise. In this way, each column will inherit the main class (`.mkdf-column-content`) styles, and will also have the newly added styles.

Another approach is to use the pseudo selectors on the `.mkdf-column-content` class, like:

```
.mkdf-column-content:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```